# Suggestion to upgrade MOSS and Infopath 2007 to Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2007, infopath, upgrade

At this time we use MOSS 2007 and InfoPath 2007. We developded more than 15 Infopath 2007 forms and a custom workflow as well as some custom extension such as custom list or setting page for the extensions.

We will upgrade the whole system with **In-place upgrade**, because we upgrade the hardware too, but we haven't got any idea about our custom code.

What we need to do? or How can we upgrade our customizations to the new system?

Our developer environment:

- Windows 2003 server 64bit
- VS 2008
- MOSS 2007, Infopath 2007

If you have got any suggestions, best practices or any other experiences, please tell me.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: by custom workflow, you mean Visual Studio Worklow or SPD workflow ? What about the volumetry ? what about the accepted interuption of service? migration are often more a project of analysing than just pressing an upgrade button.

Comment: This is a VS workflow, we use a three level approval custom workflow for more then 10 list. There are a lot of connections to database, activedirectory, to other applications for user details, web service etc and there are some background process too. So it is a very complex WF and customization (and very misgiuded too ...).

Comment: The custom workflow is supposed to work with no modification **IF** you did not change anything in the configuration. I worked on a migration where the urls changed, the authentication changed (from FBA to claims/FBA), etc... and the workflows had to be stopped before the migration occured. In all case, test test test test test test test and retest on seperate environment before actually migrating your platform.

Comment: Thank you, I keep in my mind this things, and it sounds good for us, because we can save a lot of work with porting the WF to Sharepoint 2010.